# Z score transformation for testing group differences in correlations

Tags: correlation, spss, generalized-linear-model

SPSS Help provides the following help for testing group differences in a correlation, using the GLM approach. See [link](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21478950).

It first requires that X and Y are transformed into z scores.

**Question:** When is this transformation necessary?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The GLM approach is pretty painful here, but your GLM is really doing a regression analysis, so if the variables have a different scale, you would reject equality just because of that.  By standardizing the variables, the coefficients are equivalent to correlations, so you are doing the test on equality of correlations, and scale differences don't count.